# fire and observe jQuery event for class object

Tags: jquery, events, bind, javascript-objects

Using jQuery as my base, I have 2 classes. objA & objB.

ObjB has a reference to objA. when ObjA.fn is executed, I want objB.fn to automatically execute too. I can't seem to get objB.fn to fire? What am I doing wrong?

i.e.

```
objA = function() {
    var v = 0,
    fn = function(i) {
        v = i;
        $(v).trigger('customEvent', i);
    };
    return { fn : fn };
};

objB = function(a) {
    var v2 = 0,
    myObjA = a,
    fn = function(e, i) {
        v2 = i*(-1);
    };
    $(a).bind('customEvent', fn);
    return { fn : fn };
};
var a = new objA();
var b = new objB(a);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found my answer. The problem was that I wasn't firing the event off the correct object. It's all about scope. objB can see objA, so objA needs to fire the event, not it's value. which also means I need to listen to my reference to objA to see when it's firing the event.

Correct example below:

```
objA = function() {
    var v = 0,
    fn = function(i) {
        v = i;
        $(this).trigger('customEvent', i);
    };
    return { fn : fn };
};

objB = function(a) {
    var v2 = 0,
    myObjA = a,
    fn = function(e, i) {
        v2 = i*(-1);
        console.log(v2);
    };
    $(myObjA).bind('customEvent', fn);
    return { fn : fn };
};
var a = new objA();
var b = new objB(a);

a.fn(3)
```